# Symfony2 and composer issue: "Could not parse version constraint composer.phar..."

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin, symfony-2.2

So I'm having issues trying to get composer to work again after installing the Sonata Admin Bundle on Symfony2.  When using the command `php composer.phar ....`, I get the following error message: `[UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint composer.phar: Invalid version string "composer.phar"`

It doesn't matter what action I do with composer, it always produces that error.  Well, one exception is `php composer.phar require --no-update sonata-project/media-bundle` says it updated composer.json with no error message, but didn't actually install anything.

So far I have just removed and reinstalled composer.phar with an updated version.  I'm running Symfony 2.2.1-dev on Mac OS 10.7.5 with MAMP and PHP 5.4.4.  Not sure if this is related, but I also cannot clear the cache using `php app/console cache:clear` anymore either.  I have to delete the cache via Finder.

Here's my composer.json file just in case:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": "composer.phar",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*-dev",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.1.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/common": "2.3.x-dev",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
}
```

Any help/advice would be great :)

Comment: May you add the error message, which you get running `cache:clear`?

Comment: No error messages and no message at all saying it was cleared.  Checked the cache folder and nothing gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some typos in your composer file.

Replace `"php": "composer.phar"` with `"php": ">=5.3.3"` and add the missing closing bracket at the end of your file :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*-dev",
        "sonata-project/exporter": "1.1.*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/common": "2.3.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Wow, I feel really stupid for not noticing that "php": "composer.phar" part (The closing bracket was actually in the original code).  Apparently that got altered when I stupidly just cut and paste the code to install the Sonata Media Bundle via composer without realizing the obvious typo:  http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html...  Thanks again!